# how to center/line to left >{\raggedright\arraybackslash} object

Tags: latex, tabular

I have a table and I would like the center all the columns except the first one. How to get around with this. many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\etal}{{\sl et al. }}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{0}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}
        {>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            %cccc
        }
        \toprule 
        &   (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5)   \\ [0.5ex] 
        &Tobin's Q  &Total Q    &Enterprise Value Multiple  &Operating Cash Flow    &EBITDA \\
        \midrule
        Constituency Statute (-2 or -1)     &0.2162 &0.2834*    &1.286  &0.003  &0.0009\\
        &-0.134 &-0.166 &-2.114 &-0.018 &-0.018\\
        Constituency Statute (0)    &0.0703 &0.1944 &0.8492 &0.0154 &0.0134\\
        &-0.12  &-0.201 &-1.394 &-0.015 &-0.017\\
        Constituency Statute (+1)   &0.1373 &0.1902 &1.2016 &0.006  &0.0207\\
        &-0.143 &-0.186 &-1.337 &-0.018 &-0.018\\
        Constituency Statute (+2)   &0.2084*    &0.3055**   &0.4787 &0.0152 &0.0066\\
        &-0.11  &-0.15  &-1.259 &-0.013 &-0.016\\
        Constituency Statute (3+)   &0.2221**   &0.3970***  &1.1029 &0.0003 &0.0005\\
        &-0.088 &-0.115 &-0.924 &-0.012 &-0.014\\
        Constant    &4.9142***  &3.7396***  &9.1269***  &-0.0529***     &-0.0019\\
        &-0.092 &-0.181 &-1.589 &-0.008 &-0.013\\
        Control Variables   &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes \\
        Firm FE     &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes \\
        Industry-by-Year FE     &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes \\
        State-by-Year FE    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes \\
        Observations    &28555  &28498  &28481  &27903  &28555\\
        Adjusted R2     &0.546  &0.503  &0.554  &0.654  &0.698\\
        
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{6}{@{}p{1\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize 
            This table reports the coefficient estimates of the dynamics of treatment effect of constituency statutes for the subsample of the technology \& pharmaceutical industries. The dependent variables are Tobin's Q (column 1), Total Q (column 2), Enterprise Value Multiple (column 3), Operating Cash Flow (column 4), and EBITDA (column 5). Constituency Statute (-2 or -1) indicate observations in one and two years prior to the enactment of constituency statutes, Constituency Statute (0) indicates the year of the enactment, and Constituency Statute (+1), (+2) and (3+) indicate observations in one, two, and three or more years after the enactment respectively. All control variables are lagged by one year and are suppressed for brevity. All regressions include firm, state (of location) by year, and industry (Fama-French 12 industries) by year fixed effects. Singleton observations are dropped in regressions due to fixed effects (Correia, 2015). Robust standard errors are clustered at firm’s incorporation state level and are reported in parentheses below the coefficient estimates. ***, ** and * denote statistical significance at 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level respectively. See Appendix for detailed definitions for all variables.  
        }\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Dynamics of treatment effect of constituency statutes - continued Panel B.}
    \label{tab:app4}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Again, all the `[...]` are broken :( Please fix how you paste the code to your question. Also please fix your previous question, so it remains useful for future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: No, I mean broken code like `[![\documentclass\[11pt, a4paper\]{article}`. Don't click the insert image button before pasting your code.

Comment: I see now, what do you mean.

Comment: Please also fix yesterday's question

Comment: ... and `\[htbp\]`, `\[0.5ex\] ` etc. is still broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand why you are using a `tabularx` if you don't have an `X` column, anyway, you can centre columns like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\etal}{{\sl et al. }}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{0}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}
        {>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            %cccc
        }
        \toprule 
        &   (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5)   \\[0.5ex] 
        &Tobin's Q  &Total Q    &Enterprise Value Multiple  &Operating Cash Flow    &EBITDA \\
        \midrule
        Constituency Statute (-2 or -1)     &0.2162 &0.2834*    &1.286  &0.003  &0.0009\\
        &-0.134 &-0.166 &-2.114 &-0.018 &-0.018\\
        Constituency Statute (0)    &0.0703 &0.1944 &0.8492 &0.0154 &0.0134\\
        &-0.12  &-0.201 &-1.394 &-0.015 &-0.017\\
        Constituency Statute (+1)   &0.1373 &0.1902 &1.2016 &0.006  &0.0207\\
        &-0.143 &-0.186 &-1.337 &-0.018 &-0.018\\
        Constituency Statute (+2)   &0.2084*    &0.3055**   &0.4787 &0.0152 &0.0066\\
        &-0.11  &-0.15  &-1.259 &-0.013 &-0.016\\
        Constituency Statute (3+)   &0.2221**   &0.3970***  &1.1029 &0.0003 &0.0005\\
        &-0.088 &-0.115 &-0.924 &-0.012 &-0.014\\
        Constant    &4.9142***  &3.7396***  &9.1269***  &-0.0529***     &-0.0019\\
        &-0.092 &-0.181 &-1.589 &-0.008 &-0.013\\
        Control Variables   &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes \\
        Firm FE     &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes \\
        Industry-by-Year FE     &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes \\
        State-by-Year FE    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes    &Yes \\
        Observations    &28555  &28498  &28481  &27903  &28555\\
        Adjusted R2     &0.546  &0.503  &0.554  &0.654  &0.698\\
        
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{6}{@{}p{1\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize 
            This table reports the coefficient estimates of the dynamics of treatment effect of constituency statutes for the subsample of the technology \& pharmaceutical industries. The dependent variables are Tobin's Q (column 1), Total Q (column 2), Enterprise Value Multiple (column 3), Operating Cash Flow (column 4), and EBITDA (column 5). Constituency Statute (-2 or -1) indicate observations in one and two years prior to the enactment of constituency statutes, Constituency Statute (0) indicates the year of the enactment, and Constituency Statute (+1), (+2) and (3+) indicate observations in one, two, and three or more years after the enactment respectively. All control variables are lagged by one year and are suppressed for brevity. All regressions include firm, state (of location) by year, and industry (Fama-French 12 industries) by year fixed effects. Singleton observations are dropped in regressions due to fixed effects (Correia, 2015). Robust standard errors are clustered at firm’s incorporation state level and are reported in parentheses below the coefficient estimates. ***, ** and * denote statistical significance at 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level respectively. See Appendix for detailed definitions for all variables.  
        }\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Dynamics of treatment effect of constituency statutes - continued Panel B.}
    \label{tab:app4}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```